# Como almacenar un objeto Nodo en una variable en Python?

Tags: python, lista, poo

Mi problema va en el programa principal, en una lista recursiva tengo los objetos Nodos .  Al guardar los nodos en variables mediante `a= ObtenerNodo(clave)` guarda `<Nodo.Nodo object at 0x7f3d1f6a0d68>` (al imprimir), hasta ahí todo correcto. El problema viene aquí, cuando quiero guardar en otra variable (otros nodos) `b= ObtenerNodo(clave)` guarda `None` (al imprimir) ¿Por que?, al debugear antes de retornar el Nodo lo imprimo y muestra    `<Nodo.Nodo object at 0x7f3d1f63e128>`  pero cuando imprimo la variable `b` imprime `None` lo mismo pasa al mostrar los demas Nodos. . .
A continuación las clases.

```py
class ListaRecursiva():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__elemento = None
        self.__subLista = None

    #Metodos
    def EstaVacio(self):
        return self.__elemento == None and self.__subLista == None

    def Agregar(self, elemento):
        if(self.EstaVacio()):              
            self.__elemento = elemento
            self.__subLista = ListaRecursiva() 
        else:
            self.__subLista.Agregar(elemento)

    def ObtenerNodo(self, elemento):
        if(self.EstaVacio()):
            print("Noneee")
            return None
        elif(self.__elemento.get_clave() == elemento):
            print("Nodo encontrado" ,self.__elemento.get_clave())
            print("nodo a devolver: ", self.__elemento)
            return self.__elemento #sino con get
        else:
            self.__subLista.ObtenerNodo(elemento)
    
    def MostrarLista(self):
        if (not self.EstaVacio()):
            print(str(self.__elemento) + " -> " , end="")
            self.__subLista.MostrarLista()
        else:
            print("fin")
```

La clase Nodo

```py
class Nodo():
    def __init__(self,clave):
        self.__clave = clave
        self.__estado = None
    #Propiedades
    def get_clave(self):
        return self.__clave
    def get_estado(self):
        return self.__estado

    def set_clave(self, clave):
        self.__clave == clave
    def set_estado(self, estado):
        self.__estado = estado
```

Programa principal donde al ejecutar se nota el error

```
#inicializar la lista recursiva
z=ListaRecursiva()
#Agregar nodos
z.Agregar(Nodo("a"))
z.Agregar(Nodo("b"))
z.Agregar(Nodo("c"))
#Obtener nodos
a=z.ObtenerNodo("a")
b=z.ObtenerNodo("b")
c=z.ObtenerNodo("c")
#Mostrar nodo 
print("-------------------------")
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
#A continuarcion mostrar la lista (aqui si se ve lo que deberia almacenar b,c)
z.MostrarLista()
```

De ante mano muchas gracias por sus respuestas y sugerencias.

Comment: Necesito luego utilizar la variables donde guardo nodos(a,b,c) para luego agregar su segundo atributo a Nodos. En a funciona correctamente pero en b y c obtengo un error ya que están funcionando como None y no como el objeto.

Comment: todo es un objeto :/

Comment: no será que se te olvidó poner un `return` en el `else` del método `ObtenerNodo`??

Comment: @Christian Su atributo lista es recursivo, por tanto de la sgte sublista Obtendra el Nodo

Comment: eso es lo de menos, te dijo que te falta un `return`!

Comment: Hola, me gustaría comentarte algo, puedes entrar a [este chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128316/holas)